# getting values from admin bacckend

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I would like to know how to get all the values configured by the user in the custom tab in the admin backend, which we specify in the system.xml. Is there any way I can get all these values as a single object?

Answer (score 0):

To get configuration values you can use the Mage function:
`getStoreConfig()`

Example: `Mage::getStoreConfig('sectionName/groupName/fieldName');`

You can get an entire section or group in an array if you'd like.

**To get an entire section:**

`$configSection = Mage::getStoreConfig('sectionName');`

**To get an entire group:**

`$configGroup = Mage::getStoreConfig('sectionName/groupName');`

### How to access these variables

**To get group from section array**:

`$configGroup = $configSection['groupName'];`

**To get option from section array:**

`$configOption = $configSection['groupName']['yourOption']`;

**To get option from group array:**

`$configOption = $configGroup['yourOption'];`